# Sed replace with any random word in string

Tags: awk, sed

Hello I am trying to do a replace on a file where a string is followed by any random string using sed. My original file looks like below.

```
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, myuser ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser, somedude ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, justarandomuser, somedude, anotherdude ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, another_random_user ]
```

I need to add a string called sc_admin after my random user which follows admin so that it looks like this

```
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, myuser, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser, somedude, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, justarandomuser, somedude, anotherdude, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, another_random_user, sc_admin ]
```

I am trying to run the following sed command but its not doing anything.

```
sed -r "s/\[\ admin\,\ \w+\ \]/\[\ admin\,\ \w+\,\ sc\_admin\ \]/g" local.meta
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: `admin` followed by `randomuser` or `random_user`

Comment: Do you ever have input lines that do not contain an `admin` user? If so include one of those in your question so we can see how they should be handled.

Comment: When posting sample input/output you should try to think of cases that'd be difficult to get right, not just the trivial cases. It's always much easier to match the strings you want than to not match similar strings you don't want. Try the answers provided so far if your input was `access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, mollusc_administered ]` for example (they'd fail because it contains the substring `sc_admin`) . Take a minute to think about cases where a script might fail (e.g. false matches on substrings, regexp instead of string matches) and add those to your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip lines that already contain `sc_admin`, then replace only on lines containing `admin,`:

```
sed -e '/\bsc_admin\b/b' -e '/admin,/ s/ *] *$/, sc_admin ]/' infile
```

Output:

```
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, myuser, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser, somedude, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, justarandomuser, somedude, anotherdude, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, another_random_user, sc_admin ]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you Thor. :)

Comment: Why `E`? I don't think u use  `ERE` here

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/sc_admin\>/!s/\[ admin,.*[a-z]/&, sc_admin/' input_file
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, myuser, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser, somedude, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, justarandomuser, somedude, anotherdude, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, another_random_user, sc_admin ]
```

Comment: That would fail if `randomuser` was `mollusc_administered`.

Comment: @EdMorton Good catch. However, that would be a case of adding a slash in the regex match, but yes, in its current format, it would fail.

Comment: It'd take a bit more than adding a slash in the regexp match, e.g. word boundaries if you want to go GNU-only, or testing for blanks, commas, or square brackets otherwise (I think, haven't thought it through as the OP hasn't provided sample input/output to really test it yet).

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed. Obviously, I did not think it through either ; )

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/sc_admin/ && /admin,/{gsub(/\]$/,",scadmin ]",$0)}1' filename
```

output

```
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, sc_admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, myuser ,scadmin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser ,scadmin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, randomuser, somedude ,scadmin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, justarandomuser, somedude, anotherdude ,scadmin ]
access = read : [ * ], write : [ admin, another_random_user ,scadmin ]
```